# Разный font-weight в chrome и firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Шрифт подключил через фонтфейс. В хроме сделала как все должно выглядеть, но в фф жирность шрифта меньше и текст переносится на новую строку. Пробовал использовать префикс -moz- со свойством font-weight, но все бесполезно. Как это исправить?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Larsseit_cirillic';
  src: url('Fonts/Larsseit_cirillic.ttf');
  -moz-font-family: 'Larsseit_cirillic';
  font-weight: normal;
  -moz-font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  -moz-font-style: normal;
}

.section {
  width: 647px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Larsseit_cirillic';
  font-weight: 200;
}

.edu_title_org {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  -moz-font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  width: 377%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="edu_title">
    <span class="edu_title_org">JavaScript + React, онлайн-курс</span>
    <span class="edu_title_prof">Програмист</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вы подключили одно «нормальное» начертание шрифта, а пытаетесь использовать супертонкое и жирное. Браузеры как-то пытаются съэмулировать такие начертания, но делают это по разному. По хорошему нужно просто подключить правильные начертания и не мучать браузер.

Comment: У меня тоже была такая мысль, но наверняка я этого не знал. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: И ещё одна мелочь: при использовании префиксов для свойств CSS, необходимо помнить, что их следует располагать до свойства CSS без префикса.